# iOS simulator looks different than TestFlight

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, testflight

I am relatively new to flutter and I'm having some issues with the app that I'm working on. Does anyone know why my app looks different in my ios simulator than in test flight, there are several testers and it only looks bad on my phone, on others it looks good, how can I avoid this problem? Could I have problems in other devices?
[image: Here you can see de difference between both screen]

I need that both screen can look the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the Accessibility settings of the phones.

On iOS, these settings are found under:

Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size

Options that affect this:

1. Bold Text
2. Larger Text (and Larger Accessibility Sizes)

These settings will modify the `textScaleFactor` of your `MediaQuery`.

Solution:

1. Create a layout that can handle up to a certain text size.
2. Limit the maximum `textScaleFactor` of your application as needed:

Sample code:

```
MediaQuery(
  data: mediaQuery.copyWith(
    /// Determine your maximum textScaleFactor, I use 1.25 as an example.
    textScaleFactor: mediaQuery.textScaleFactor.clamp(1.0, 1.25),
  ),
  child: Scaffold(body: child),
)
```

Comment: Oh my god, it was that ! thank you ! I thought I had to change something in my code and it was the settings of my phone

Comment: Thank for this too, the code that works for me is this `MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context).clamp(1.0, 1.25),
      ),
  child: Scaffold(body: child),
)`